# compare two values in a single column depending on a different column

Tags: sql, oracle

**Data**

[image: Table Data]

**Condition**

Find the cust_name and cust_id when the param_type is 'hand' and param_name left having param_value lesser than that of prama_name 'right's param_value

**Query Tried**

```
select distinct    
    X.CUST_ID,X.CUST_NAME,X.PARAM_TYPE,X.PARAM_NAME,X.PARAM_VALUE,
    Y.PARAM_NAME,Y.PARAM_VALUE
from test01 x , test01 y, test01 z
where Z.PARAM_TYPE = 'hand'
and X.PARAM_NAME = 'left'
and Y.PARAM_NAME = 'right'
and X.CUST_ID = Y.CUST_ID
and X.CUST_NAME = Y.CUST_NAME
and Z.PARAM_TYPE = X.PARAM_TYPE
and Z.PARAM_TYPE = Y.PARAM_TYPE
and Y.PARAM_VALUE>X.PARAM_VALUE
```

**Result**
[image: Query Result/Final Result]

**Question**
The query is giving correct value, is there any other way as the query takes lot of time.

Comment: please explain better

Comment: and also please show us that you have put in some effort yourself

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output, which may help in understand your question a little better.

Comment: Let's say you have no clue where to start, so you didn't try anything yet. But, please add some details about your question. What you need and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Question is unclear.

Comment: Actually it is my first time posting questions so had to face few glitches, I have updated proper data and query. Please look into tjis also let me know if anything else is requiured.

Comment: It sounds like a performance question - can you tell us what indexes you have on the table? It will be useful for you to explore the `explain` operation which tells you what it is likely to be expensive from a performance point of view and what is not in your query.

Comment: The table contains B-tree index. Actually i was trying to ask if there are any other way of fetching the desired data without using self join. Like using Connect by or any thing else.

Answer (score 1):

Only one self join is sufficient in your case,
you don't need to join the table twice:

```
select X.CUST_ID,X.CUST_NAME,X.PARAM_TYPE,
       X.PARAM_NAME,X.PARAM_VALUE, Y.PARAM_NAME,Y.PARAM_VALUE
from test01 x
join  test01 y 
on
  x.param_type = 'hand'
  and y.param_type = x.param_type
  and x.param_name = 'left'
  and y.param_name = 'right'
  and X.CUST_ID = Y.CUST_ID
  and X.CUST_NAME = Y.CUST_NAME
  and x.param_value < y.param_value
```